# can't get d3.xml to POST correctly

Tags: ajax, d3.js

I tried to POST/GET some Vars to a php-file via AJAX/d3.xml, but a print_r($_POST/$_GET) inside the php, tells me they're empty. Even the example on the [doc](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_xml) won't work for me.

```
d3.xml("xxx.php")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-url-encoded")
    /*
        .get("a=2&b=3", function(error, data) {
      console.log(error);
    })
        */
        .post("a=2&b=3", function(error, data) {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .on("load", createTable(data));
```

The console tells me that there is a POST request but under POST (on Firefox, not on Chrome) it lists the Vars in one line "a=2&b=3", instead of 
      
a = 2
      b = 3

 as it usually does. 
What is it that I'm not getting?

Comment: Are you mixing up d3.xml with d3.xhr?

Comment: Don't think so. Changing it to d3.xhr doesn't change anything. Also  the php script should return valid xml. At the moment, of course, it returns an error because the POST/GET is empty. But generally, that is what d3.xml is for, isn't it?

Comment: My understanding of d3.xml is that it does a GET request and passes a parsed XML payload into a callback.  To construct an AJAX request more explicitly (or a POST request at all) I thought you needed to use d3.xhr directly.  d3.xml is implemented internally with d3.xhr.

Comment: OK, tried to understand it for hours, but I totally don't get it.  My console.log tells me, that even with d3.xml it seems to switch between POST/GET request depending on what is set. As I said above, with d3.xhr I got the exact same probs. If I put the vars directly into the d3.xml call, i.e. the url, it works by the way. But what function do the parameters in ".post("a=2&b=3")..." have, if not parameters for an AJAX request?

Comment: Yeah, something is funny here.  If you can put an example up on jsfiddle I can take a look.

Comment: I set it up [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WaT6r/2/). Very basic without comments cause it's rather obvious. You don't get back any xml, but that doesn't matter I think cause it's about the params being not send. I now get it from the docs that ".get()" doesn't accept any params as an argument, only a callback. What I still don't get is why the .post("a=2") doesn't send any params, both using d3.xml and d3.xhr. The console.log in Firefox lists "a=2" in the POST section, but not as "Parameter" as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, apologies for the confusion in the comments.  I was looking at the source for an old version of d3.  In the newer code, it is indeed true that if you do not provide a callback to d3.xml it returns an xhr request that you can configure directly.  (If you do provide a callback, it executes a GET right away as before).

You're going to hate this, so get ready. :) Your issue is because you have an extra dash in your Content-Type header.  You have:

```
application/x-www-form-url-encoded
```

but it should be

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Looking at a modified version of your jsfiddle in Firefox, I see the arguments show up in the list view as expected:  http://jsfiddle.net/WaT6r/3/

Comment: Yeah, I hate this! And I feel like an idiot. But thank you so much! It was driving me nuts not to understand why the arguments didn't show up in list view.