# Call Perl script using D3 Xhr

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nvd3.js, mod-perl

I have a web application with an HTML form. When I press submit I want to submit the values from this form to a perl script, parseDatabaseData_v2.pl, which get's data from a database and creates a JSON string of that data.

Then, I'd like to visualize this JSON data using a D3 graph.
The following code using jquery ajax works, and returns JSON from the perl script as expected.

```
    var runFromDate = $('#runDateSelectBox1').val();
    var runToDate = $('#runDateSelectBox2').val();
    var barcode = $('#barcodesSelectBox').val();

    var dataString = 'runFromDate='+ runFromDate + '&runToDate=' + runToDate + '&barcode=' + barcode;

    // ajax command
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './cgi-bin/parseDatabaseData_v2.pl',
        async: true,
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
              console.log("succesfully called script");

        }
    }); // end of ajax command
```

In the perl script I use `cgi->param('runFromDate');` to get the posted parameters.

However, since I'm visualizing the data using NVD3's `lineWithFocusChart` I want to call the script using d3.xhr.

When I create the following d3.xhr request the script doesn't work (it get's called, but is unable to get the parameters).

```
    var runFromDate = document.getElementById("runDateSelectBox1").value;
    var runToDate = document.getElementById("runDateSelectBox2").value;
    var barcode = document.getElementById("barcodesSelectBox").value;

    var dataString = 'runFromDate='+ runFromDate + '&runToDate=' + runToDate + '&barcode=' + barcode;

    d3.xhr("./cgi-bin/parseDatabaseData_v2.pl")
      .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-url-encoded")
      .post(dataString,function(error, data){
          console.log("succesfully called script");
              console.log(data);
      });
```

I've tried various ways of formatting the datastring including formatting it as JSON as explained at [the D3 API Reference](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#send).

I'd be most grateful if someone was willing to help me with this.

Thanks,

Koen

Comment: Could you add what the value of `error` is? (or is it null?) See this answer for the usual patten of doing this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22693549/897489

Comment: I just checked it, it's null.

Comment: Have you compared what is sent in the jQuery and d3 examples in the 'Net' tab of firebug? Could you also give an example of the string value of `dataString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a spurious hyphen between url and encoded!

Change

```
.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-url-encoded")
```

to

```
.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Looks like you are not the only one as [this other recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22666567/897489) shows. Seems the offending code has been in the d3.js wiki so I have updated it too.

Comment: This seems to solve it. Thank you very much Christopher.